# what does "$K2ko{$D}{$C} = 1" do in perl?

Tags: perl

```
cat inputfile
A<b>Metabolism</b>
B
B  <b>Overview</b>
C    01200 Carbon metabolism [PATH:ko01200]
D      K00844  HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]
D      K12407  GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
...
```

#

```
open KO,'<',"inputfile" or die $!;
my ($A,$B,$C,$D,$path_DESC,$KO_DESC);
my %K2ko; my %K2DESC; my %ko2desc;
while (<KO>) {
    if (/^A<b>(.+)<\/b>/) {$A=$1;}
    elsif (/^B\s+<b>(.+)<\/b>/) {$B=$1;}
    elsif (/^C\s+\d+\s+(.+)\s+\[PATH:(ko\d+)\]/) {
        $path_DESC=$1;
        $C=$2;
        $ko2desc{$C} = "$A\t$B\t$path_DESC";
    }
    elsif (/^D\s+(K\d+)\s+(.*)/) {
        $D=$1;
        $KO_DESC=$2;
        $K2ko{$D}{$C} = 1;
        $K2DESC{$D} = $KO_DESC;
    }
}
close KO;
```

#

Could anyone would like to tell me what does  "$K2ko{$D}{$C} = 1"  do in the perl script?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample data:

```
if (/^A<b>(.+)<\/b>/) {$A=$1;}
```

sets `$A` to `'Metabolism'`

```
elsif (/^B\s+<b>(.+)<\/b>/) {$B=$1;}
```

sets `$B` to `'Overview'`

```
elsif (/^C\s+\d+\s+(.+)\s+\[PATH:(ko\d+)\]/) {...}
```

sets `$path_DESC` to `'Carbon metabolism'`, `$C` to `'ko01200'` and the hash

```
$ko2desc{'ko01200'} = "Metabolism\tOverview\tCarbon metabolism"
```

and finally

```
elsif (/^D\s+(K\d+)\s+(.*)/) {...}
```

will set

```
$D='K12407';
$KO_DESC='GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]';
$K2ko{'K12407'}{'ko01200'} = 1;
$K2DESC{'K12407'} = 'GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]';
```

`$K2ko` is an hash of hashes, setting it to 1 you can easily see where the component `K12407` is used:

```
print join ',', keys %{$K2ko{'K12407'}};
```

Comment: May I assign any 'int' or 'string' to `$K2ko{$D}{$C}`, such as `$K2ko{$D}{$C}=2;` `$K2ko{$D}{$C}=a` and so on? Is that OK?

Comment: @user6037276 yep. We use string or integer. But if you use string use quotes for interpolation for example `$K2ko{$D}{$C}="a";`

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [hash of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES), which gives you a multidimensional hash. Here, "1" is the value for the above mentioned hash key.

Try to use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.154/Dumper.pm) for know the structure of your data.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %K2ko;
my $D = "val1";
my $C = "val2";
$K2ko{$D}{$C} = 1;
print Dumper \%K2ko;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'val1' => {
                      'val2' => 1
                    }
        };
```